# Java: Generate dot-separated property path from transitive object hierarchy

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

There is a functionality available in common beanutils, that lets you retrieve property value from the dot notation (even for nested properties).
I'd need a reverse functionality. To generate the dot notation from the 2 Objects beeing transitively referenced.
Is there any 3rd party library capable of that, or do you have an idea for the implementation?

E.g. having class hierarchy:

```
public class Teacher {

    String name;
    List<Claz> classes;

    public Teacher(String name, List<Claz> classes) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setClasses(classes);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Claz> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

    public void setClasses(List<Claz> classes) {
        this.classes = classes;
    }

}

public class Claz {
    String name;
    List<Student> students;

    public Claz(String name, List<Student> students) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setStudents(students);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
}
public class Student {

    String name;

    public Student(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The test proves commons-beanutils work as expected:

```
 @Test
    public void nestedProp() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {


        Teacher teacher = new Teacher(
                "John",
                Arrays.asList(
                        new Claz("1.A", Arrays.asList(new Student("Peter"), new Student("Paul"))),
                        new Claz("1.B", Arrays.asList(new Student("Jane"), new Student("Paula")))
                )
        );
        assertEquals("Paul", PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(teacher, "classes[0].students[1].name"));
    }
```

Now I need a functionality, that would generate me `classes[0].students[1].name` from method similar to:

```
String getDotNotation(Class rootClass, Class leafClass, java.lang.reflect.Field leafField) {
...
}
```

where rootClass  would be in my case `Teacher`, leafClass would be in my case `Student` and field would refer to `Student.name` field.

Comment: I implemented this once in C# and it is rather straight-forward (but I don't have the code anymore): use reflection to get the fields, loop over them, recurse for nested complex objects. Make sure you handle cycles in the graph properly to not end up in a stackoverflow or infinite loop.

Comment: @knittl correct, but code sample would be preferred

Comment: Are you familiar with using reflection? If so the code should be easy enough - just try it :)
To break cycles I'd keep track of classes that have already been visited and ignore those.

Comment: I think the difficult part will be replicating the indices of the arrays. Why would this method return `"classes[0].students[1].name"` and not e.g., `"classes[2].students[5].name"`?

Comment: yes, I'm aware of reflection, but was rather hoping for available 3.rd party library implementation, than maintaining my own

Comment: @PeterButkovic if you are looking for 3rd party tools, then this question is off-topic as per stackoverflow policy. One of the close reasons: »Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.«

Comment: I find the comment from Slaw to the point: the signature of `getDotNotation` does not guarantee a unique result. Maybe specifying the root and a condition to look for in the hierarchy would be more appropriate. Also `Field` may be too complicated for users to work with, `String` (for a field name) would be more convenient since you will be dealing with reflection internally anyway. E.g. a signature as: `String getDotNotation(Object root, Predicate<Object> predicate, String fieldName)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implemenation. It converts an object tree into a list of paths (dot notation) with their value.

The output for your sample object:

```
classes[0].name = "1.A"
classes[0].students[0].name = "Peter"
classes[0].students[1].name = "Paul"
classes[1].name = "1.B"
classes[1].students[0].name = "Jane"
classes[1].students[1].name = "Paula"
name = "John"
```

Limitations of this implementation:

- Doesn't handle cycles in your graph. If you have a circular reference, this method will run forever
- Not optimized for efficiency
- Cannot handle custom implementations of the `Collection` or `Map` interfaces and pretends that they are arrays. Will drop any properties additionally defined in your custom class.
- Silently ignores non-bean objects (objects without getters)
- Aborts with an exception if it encounters an error

Anyway, here goes:

```
class GronTest {
    @Test
    void simpleStringArray() {
        assertEquals(
                List.of("[0] = \"a\"", "[1] = \"b\""),
                paths(new String[]{"a", "b"}));
    }

    @Test
    void simpleBoolArray() {
        assertEquals(
                List.of("[0] = true", "[1] = false"),
                paths(new boolean[]{true, false}));
    }

    @Test
    void simpleIntArray() {
        assertEquals(
                List.of("[0] = 1", "[1] = -2"),
                paths(new int[]{1, -2}));
    }

    @Test
    void simpleLongArray() {
        assertEquals(
                List.of("[0] = -1", "[1] = 2"),
                paths(new long[]{-1L, 2L}));
    }

    @Test
    void simpleFloatArray() {
        assertEquals(
                List.of("[0] = 4.2", "[1] = -13.37"),
                paths(new float[]{4.2f, -13.37f}));
    }

    @Test
    void simpleDoubleArray() {
        assertEquals(
                List.of("[0] = -4.2", "[1] = 13.37"),
                paths(new double[]{-4.2d, 13.37d}));
    }

    @Test
    void simpleStringList() {
        assertEquals(
                List.of("[0] = \"a\"", "[1] = \"b\""),
                paths(List.of("a", "b")));
    }

    @Test
    void simpleIntegerSet() {
        assertEquals(
                List.of("[0] = -1"),
                paths(Set.of(-1)));
    }

    @Test
    void simpleStringDoubleMap() {
        assertEquals(
                List.of("[\"key\"] = 1.0"),
                paths(Map.of("key", 1.0d)));
    }

    @Test
    void simpleObject() {
        @RequiredArgsConstructor
        @Getter
        class Person {
            private final String name;
        }

        assertEquals(
                List.of("name = \"bob\""),
                paths(new Person("bob")));
    }

    @Test
    void nestedObject() {
        @RequiredArgsConstructor
        @Getter
        class Pet {
            private final String name;
            private final int age;
        }

        @RequiredArgsConstructor
        @Getter
        class Person {
            private final String name;
            private final List<Pet> pets;
        }

        final Person person = new Person(
                "alice",
                List.of(
                        new Pet("garfield", 42),
                        new Pet("scooby-doo", 7)));
        assertEquals(
                List.of(
                        "name = \"alice\"",
                        "pets[0].age = 42",
                        "pets[0].name = \"garfield\"",
                        "pets[1].age = 7",
                        "pets[1].name = \"scooby-doo\""),
                paths(person));
    }

    static List<String> paths(final Object obj) {
        return Gron.paths(obj);
    }

}

public final class Gron {
    private Gron() {}

    public static List<String> paths(final Object obj) {
        return paths("", obj);
    }

    public static List<String> paths(final String path, final Object obj) {
        final List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();

        if (obj instanceof String) {
            return List.of(String.format("%s = \"%s\"", path, obj));
        } else if (isBoxedPrimitive(obj)) {
            return List.of(String.format("%s = %s", path, obj));
        } else if (obj.getClass().isArray()) {
            arrayPaths(paths, path, obj);
        } else if (obj instanceof Collection) {
            // TODO extra properties of custom classes implementing Collection
            collectionPaths(paths, path, (Collection<?>) obj);
        } else if (obj instanceof Map) {
            // TODO extra properties of custom classes implementing Map
            mapPaths(paths, path, (Map<?, ?>) obj);
        } else {
            beanPaths(paths, path, obj);
        }

        return paths;
    }

    private static void arrayPaths(final List<String> paths, final String path, final Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof int[]) {
            final int[] ints = (int[]) obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
                paths.add(indexed(path, i) + " = " + ints[i]);
            }
        } else if (obj instanceof long[]) {
            final long[] longs = (long[]) obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < longs.length; i++) {
                paths.add(indexed(path, i) + " = " + longs[i]);
            }
        } else if (obj instanceof boolean[]) {
            final boolean[] booleans = (boolean[]) obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < booleans.length; i++) {
                paths.add(indexed(path, i) + " = " + booleans[i]);
            }
        } else if (obj instanceof float[]) {
            final float[] floats = (float[]) obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < floats.length; i++) {
                paths.add(indexed(path, i) + " = " + floats[i]);
            }
        } else if (obj instanceof double[]) {
            final double[] doubles = (double[]) obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++) {
                paths.add(indexed(path, i) + " = " + doubles[i]);
            }
        } else {
            final Object[] objects = (Object[]) obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                paths.addAll(paths(indexed(path, i), objects[i]));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void collectionPaths(final List<String> paths, final String path, final Collection<?> obj) {
        int idx = 0;
        for (final Object current : obj) {
            paths.addAll(paths(indexed(path, idx), current));
            ++idx;
        }
    }

    private static void mapPaths(final List<String> paths, final String path, final Map<?, ?> obj) {
        for (final Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : obj.entrySet()) {
            paths.addAll(paths(keyed(path, entry.getKey()), entry.getValue()));
        }
    }

    private static void beanPaths(final List<String> paths, final String path, final Object obj) {
        try {
            final BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(obj.getClass(), Object.class);
            for (final PropertyDescriptor pd : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
                final Method readMethod = pd.getReadMethod();
                if (readMethod != null) {
                    final Object value = readMethod.invoke(obj);
                    paths.addAll(paths(nested(path, pd.getName()), value));
                }
            }
        } catch (final IntrospectionException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isBoxedPrimitive(final Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Boolean
                || obj instanceof Integer
                || obj instanceof Long
                || obj instanceof Float
                || obj instanceof Double;
    }

    private static String nested(final String path, final String propName) {
        return path.isEmpty()
                ? propName
                : path + '.' + propName;
    }

    private static String keyed(final String path, final Object key) {
        return path + "[\"" + key + "\"]";
    }

    private static String indexed(final String path, final int idx) {
        return path + '[' + idx + ']';
    }

}
```